# How to determine string S can be made from string T by deleting some characters, but at most K successive characters

Tags: string, algorithm

Sorry for the long title :)

In this problem, we have string `S` of length `n`, and string `T` of length `m`. We can check whether `S` is a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of string `T` in time complexity O(n+m). It's really simple.

I am curious about: what if we can delete at most `K` successive characters? For example, if `K = 2`, we can make `"ab"` from `"accb"`, but not from `"abcccb"`. I want to check if it's possible very fast.

I could only find obvious `O(nm)`: check if it's possible for every suffix pairs in string `S` and string `T`. I thought maybe greedy algorithm could be possible, but if `K = 2`, the case `S = "abc"` and `T = "ababbc"` is a counterexample.

Is there any fast solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Interesting question.  In standard subsequences, you just 'greedily' gobble up characters.  But in this problem, you sometimes want to be less greedy in order to keep the gaps between characters smaller.

Comment: Any preferred language?  I know this is algorithmic, but sometimes it's easy to communicate a complex algorithm by giving (pseudo-)code.

Comment: Here's a nasty test case. K=10.  S is a string of identical letters, e.g. `aaaaaaaaaa` (make that K `a`s, for simplicity).  T begins with K underscores (i.e. 10 underscores).  Then it has K*K (i.e. 100) `a`s.  The purpose here is to stretch it out as much as possible.  Finally we add another K underscores on the end.  This has exactly one valid solution, but lots of 'nearly-solutions'.  It can slow down the algorithm.

Comment: BTW should _trailing trash_ be allowed ? (for instance: search `ab` in `abxxxxxxxxxx` with a max skiplength of 2)

Comment: And can you say anything about the relative values of the constants K, N and M?  Are you willing to assume that K will be (much) smaller than N?  What size could M be?  I suspect the choice of algorithm will depend on these quantities.

Comment: Would you indicate more clearly about the `O(nm)` approach? I kind of suspect whether that approach will work.

Comment: What do you mean by "successive" characters? Are we allowed to delete more than `K` characters if they're not grouped together? E.g., if `K = 2`, `S = "abc"` and `T = "addbddc"` should the answer be `true` or `false`?

Comment: @jacobm absolutely true :

Comment: So what is the "obvious" `O(nm)` solution? The only "obvious" solution that I see I is something like `O(m*K^n)`.

Comment: @LovePaper @jacobm. @LovePaper you wrote that: if `K = 2`, the case `S = "abc"` and `T = "ababbc"` is a counterexample, but `S = xxabxc`

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Of course you're right. That's an counterexample of a simple greedy algorithm. I'm sorry if you were confused.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19921040/1737401) is what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

(Update:  I've rewritten the opening of this answer to include a discussion of complexity and to discussion some alternative methods and potential risks.)

(Short answer, the only real improvement above the O(nm) approach that I can think of is to observe that we don't usually need to compute all *n* times *m* entries in the table.  We can calculate only those cells we need.  But in practice it might be very good, depending on the dataset.)

*Clarify the problem:* We have a string `S` of length `n`, and a string `T` of length `m`.  The maximum allowed gap is `k` - this gap is to be enforced at the beginning and end of the string also.  The gap is the number of unmatched characters between two matched characters - i.e. if the letters are adjacent, that is a gap of `0`, not `1`.

Imagine a table with `n+1` rows and `m+1` columns.

```
      0  1  2  3  4  ... m
     --------------------
0   | ?  ?  ?  ?  ?      ?
1   | ?  ?  ?  ?  ?      ?
2   | ?  ?  ?  ?  ?      ?
3   | ?  ?  ?  ?  ?      ?
... |
n   | ?  ?  ?  ?  ?      ?
```

At first, we we could define that the entry in row `r` and column `c` is a binary flag that tells us whether the first `r` characters of of `S` is a valid `k`-subsequence of the first `c` characters of `T`.  (Don't worry yet how to *compute* these values, or even whether these values are *useful*, we just need to *define* them clearly first.)

However, this binary-flag table isn't very useful.  It's not possible to easily calculate one cell as a function of nearby cells.  Instead, we need each cell to store slightly more information.  As well as recording whether the relevant strings are a valid subsequence, we need to record the number of consecutive unmatched characters at the end of our substring of `T` (the substring with `c` characters).  For example, if the first `r=2` characters of `S` are `"ab"` and the first `c=3` characters of `T` are `"abb"`, then there are two possible matches here:  The first characters obviously match with each other, but the `b` can match with either of the latter `b`.  Therefore, we have a choice of leaving *one* or *zero* unmatched `b`s at the end.  Which one do we record in the table?

The answer is that, if a cell has multiple valid values, then we take the smallest one.  It's logical that we want to make life as easy as possible for ourselves while matching the remainder of the string, and therefore that the smaller the gap at the end, the better.  Be wary of other incorrect optmizations - we do not want to match as many characters as possible or as few characters. That can backfire.  But it is logical, for a given pair of strings `S,T`, to find the match (if there are any valid matches) that minimizes the gap at the end.

One other observation is that if the string `S` is much shorter than `T`, then it cannot match.  This depends on `k` also obviously.  The maximum length that `S` can cover is `rk`, if this is less than `c`, then we can easily mark `(r,c)` as `-1`.

(Any other optimization statements that can be made?)

We do not need to compute all the values in this table.  The number of different possible states is k+3.  They start off in an 'undefined' state (`?`).  If a matching is not possible for the pair of (sub)strings, the state is `-`.  If a matching is possible, then the score in the cell will be a number between 0 and k inclusive, recording the smallest possible number of unmatched consecutive characters at the end.  This gives us a total of k+3 states.

We are interested only in the entry in the bottom right of the table.  If `f(r,c)` is the function that computes a particular cell, then we are interested only in `f(n,m)`.  The value for a particular cell can be computed as a function of the values nearby.  We can build a recursive algorithm that takes `r` and `c` as input and performs the relevant calculations and lookups in term of the nearby values.  If this function looks up `f(r,c)` and finds a `?`, it will go ahead and compute it and then store the answer.

It is important to store the answer as the algorithm may query the same cell many times.  But also, some cells will never be computed.  We just start off attempting to calculate one cell (the bottom right) and just lookup-and-calculate-and-store as necessary.

This is the "obvious" O(nm) approach.  The only optimization here is the observation that we don't need to calculate all the cells, therefore this should bring the complexity below O(nm).  Of course, with really nasty datasets, you may end up calculating almost all of the cells!  Therefore, it's difficult to put an official complexity estimate on this.

Finally, I should say how to compute a particular cell `f(r,c)`:

1. If `r==0` and `c <= k`, then `f(r,c) = 0`.  *An empty string can match any string with up to `k` characters in it.*
2. If `r==0` and `c >  k`, then `f(r,c) = -1`. *Too long for a match.*
3. There are only two other ways a cell can have a successful state.  We first try:
4. - If `S[r]==T[c]` and `f(r-1,c-1) != -1`, then `f(r,c) = 0`. *This is the best case - a match with no trailing gap.*
5. - If that didn't work, we try the next best thing. If `f(r,c-1) != -1` and `f(r,c) < k`, then `f(r,c) = f(r,c-1)+1`.
6. - If neither of those work, then `f(r,c) = -1`.

---

The rest of this answer is my initial, Haskell-based approach.  One advantage of it is that it 'understands' that it needn't compute every cell, only computing cells where necessary.  But it could make the inefficiency of calculating one cell many times.

*Also note that the Haskell approach is effectively approaching the problem in a mirror image - it trying to build matches from the end substrings of `S` and `T` where minimal *leading* bunch of unmatched characters.  I don't have the time to rewrite it in its 'mirror image' form!

---

A recursive approach should work.  We want a function that will take three arguments, int `K`, String `S`, and String `T`.  However, we don't just want a boolean answer as to whether S is a valid k-subsequence of T.

For this recursive approach, if S is a valid k-subsequence, we also want to know about the best subsequence possible by returning how few characters from the start of T can be dropped.  We want to find the 'best' subsequence.  If a k-subsequence is not possible for S and T, then we return -1, but if it is possible then we want to return the smallest number of characters we can pull from T while retaining the k-subsequence property.

```
    helloworld
      l    r d
```

This is a valid 4-subsequence, but the biggest gap has (at most) four characters (`lowo`).  This is the best subsequence because it leaves a gap of just two characters at the start (`he`).  Alternatively, here is another valid k-subsequence with the same strings, but it's not as good because it leaves a gap of three at the start:

```
    helloworld
       l   r d
```

This is written in Haskell, but it should be easy enough to rewrite in any other language.  I'll break it down in more detail below.

```
best :: Int -> String -> String -> Int
--      K      S         T         return
--          where len(S) <= len(T)

best    k      []        t_string       -- empty S is a subsequence of anything!
        | length(t_string) <= k       = length(t_string)
        | length(t_string) >  k       = -1

best    k      sss@(s:ss) []       = (-1)  -- if T is empty, and S is non-empty, then no subsequence is possible
best    k      sss@(s:ss) tts@(t:ts)       -- both are non-empty.  Various possibilities:
        | s == t  &&   best k ss  ts /= -1     =  0    --  if  s==t, and if    best k ss ts != -1, then we have the best outcome
        | best k sss ts /= -1 
                  &&   best k sss ts < k       = 1+ (best k sss ts)  -- this is the only other possibility for a valid k-subsequence
        | otherwise                            = -1     -- no more options left, return -1 for failure.
```

---

A line-by-line analysis:
(A comment in Haskell starts with `--`)

```
best :: Int -> String -> String -> Int
```

A function that takes an Int, and two Strings, and that returns an Int.  The return value is to be -1 if a k-subsequence is not possible.  Otherwise it will return an integer between 0 and K (inclusive) telling us the smallest possible gap at the start of T.

We simply deal with the cases in order.

```
best    k      []        t       -- empty S is a subsequence of anything!
        | length(t) <= k       = length(t)
        | length(t) >  k       = -1
```

Above, we handle the case where S is empty (`[]`).  This is simple, as an empty string is always a valid subsequence.  But to test if it is a valid *k-subsequence*, we must calculate the length of T.

```
best    k      sss@(s:ss) []       = (-1)
   -- if T is empty, and S is non-empty, then no subsequence is possible
```

That comment explains it.  This leaves us with the situations where both strings are non-empty:

```
best    k      sss@(s:ss) tts@(t:ts)       -- both are non-empty.  Various possibilities:
        | s == t  &&   best k ss  ts /= -1     =  0    --  if  s==t, and if    best k ss ts != -1, then we have the best outcome
        | best k sss ts /= -1 
                  &&   best k sss ts < k       = 1+ (best k sss ts)  -- this is the only other possibility for a valid k-subsequence
        | otherwise                            = -1     -- no more options left, return -1 for failure.
```

`tts@(t:ts)` matches a non-empty string.  The name of the string is `tts`.  But there is also a convenient trick in Haskell to allow you to give names to the first letter in the string (`t`) and the remainder of the string (`ts`).  Here `ts` should be read aloud as the plural of `t` - the `s` suffix here means 'plural'.  We say have have a `t` and some `ts` and together they make the full (non-empty) string.

That last block of code deals with the case where both strings are non-empty.  The two strings are called `sss` and `tts`.  But to save us the hassle of writing `head sss` and `tail sss` to access the first letter, and the string-remainer, of the string, we simply use `@(s:ss)` to tell the compiler to store those quantities into variables `s` and `ss`.  If this was C++ for example, you'd get the same effect with `char s = sss[0];` as the first line of your function.

The best situation is that the first characters match `s==t` and the remainder of the strings are a valid k-subsequence `best k sss ts /= -1`. This allows us to return 0.

The only other possibility for success if if the current complete string (`sss`) is a valid k-subsequence of the remainder of the other string (`ts`).  We add 1 to this and return, but making an exception if the gap would grow too big.

It's *very* important not to change the order of those last five lines.  They are order in decreasing order of how 'good' the score is.  We want to test for, and return the very best possibilities first.

Comment: Bear with me, I've just discovered some simplification that is possible (and a bug in the first version of my code!)

Comment: Updated it now.  When both strings are non-empty, there are just two possibilities for success.  First scenario is that the first characters of both strings match *and* the remainder strings are k-subsequences of each other.  Second scenario is that we skip over the first character of t and find a valid subsequence (with a gap of *at most* k-1).  If those two possibilities are exhausted, then we have failure.

Comment: Would you indicate the time complexity of your approach?

Comment: @jeffrey,  I'm still thinking and I'm not sure!

Answer (score 2):

Naive recursive solution. Bonus := return value is the number of ways that the string can be matched.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned skipneedle(char *haystack, char *needle, unsigned skipmax)
{
unsigned found,skipped;

// fprintf(stderr, "skipneedle(%s,%s,%u)\n", haystack, needle, skipmax);

if ( !*needle) return strlen(haystack) <= skipmax ? 1 : 0 ;

found = 0;
for (skipped=0; skipped <= skipmax ; haystack++,skipped++ ) {
        if ( !*haystack ) break;
        if ( *haystack == *needle) {
                found += skipneedle(haystack+1, needle+1, skipmax);
                }
        }
return found;
}

int main(void)
{
char *ab = "ab";
char *test[] = {"ab" , "accb" , "abcccb" , "abcb", NULL}
        , **cpp;

for (cpp = test; *cpp; cpp++ ) {
        printf( "[%s,%s,%u]=%u \n"
                , *cpp, ab, 2
                , skipneedle(*cpp, ab, 2) );
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make a tough test dataset?  Long strings where there is only one match, and where that match is hard to find, but there are very many 'nearly-matches' to screw up the algorithm?

Comment: Well, That's why I added the string array (to catch the "abcb" case, which should return 2) A more exhaustive test could supply the haystack strings via stdin, and the needle as argv[1].

Comment: Here's another optimization you could use.  Please check it though, I'm scared of off-by-one errors.  Just before `found=0;`  you could have `if ( (strlen(needle)+1) * (skipmax+1) > strlen(haystack)+1 ) return 0;`.  This tests if the needle is long enough to reach out over all the remaining haystack.

Comment: The code is just a proof-of-concept. The obvious optimisation is to avoid the recursion (this needs an explicit stack of max depth = *haystacksize*) This could be needed if the haystackstring is *really* large) Another optimisation is to immediately return _success_ once the first match is found (instead of finding all the matches and returning their count) Other optimisations will be rather marginal, IMHO.

Comment: ... woah.  I've just noticed it's spending all its time doing `strlen`!  Better to arrange to pass the size of the strings also, so that it isn't recomputing the length regularly.  Anyway, now that `strlen` is avoided, I've tested the effect of `if ( (len_nee+1) * (skipmax+1) > len_hay+1 ) return 0;` and it changes the runtime from 11.00s down to 0.04s .  That's for K=1,S=10 x `a`,T=[10 x `_`,100 x `a`,10 x `_`].  (clang-3.3, `-O2`)

Comment: Yes, for real large strings that should be beneficial, and would also allow '\0' to be present in the chunks (see memmem() for example), otherwise the behavior can get kind of quadratic.

Comment: In my method, each call of `best` makes at most two recursive calls to `best`, in both cases consuming one character from T ('the haystack').  Whereas yours could make more than two, perhaps up to `skipmax` calls inside the loop.  The complexity analysis isn't easy though, we each have a number of optimizations (I think we share a lot though).

Comment: The other obvious solution, especially for small alphabet size (DNA) is to construct a DFA for the needle, and use that to drive a stack machine.

Comment: This looks like the "obvious" solution that occurred to me also, but isn't this more like `O(k^n)` than `O(nm)`?

Answer (score 1):

An O(p*n) solution where p = number of subsequences possible of S in T.

Scan the string T and maintain a list of possible subsequences of S that would have
1. Index of last character found and
2. Number of characters to be deleted found

Continue to update this list at each character of T.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your asking for, but you could create a list of characters from each String, and search for instances of the one list in the other, then if(list2.length-K > list1.length) return false.

Comment: The arrangement of each string can't be changed, so I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a proposed algorithm : - O(|T|*k) average case

1> scan T and store character indices in Hash Table :-

eg. S = "abc"  T = "ababbc"

Symbol table entries : -

a = 1 3

b = 2 4 5

c = 6

2.> as we know isValidSub(S,T) = isValidSub(S(0,j),T) && (isValidSub(S(j+1,N),T)||....isValidSub(S(j+K,T),T))

a.> we will use the bottom up approach to solve above problem

b.> we will maintain an valid array Valid(len(S)) where each record points to a Hash Table (Explained as we go along solving further)

c.> Start from the last element of S, Look up for the indices stored corresponding to the character in Symbol Table

eg. in above example S[last] = "c"

in Symbol Table c = 6

Now we put records like (5,6) , (4,6) ,.... (6-k-1,6) into Hash table at Valid(last)

Explanation : - as s(6,len(S)) is valid subsequence hence s(0,6-i) ++ s(6,len(S)) (where i is in range(1,k+1)) is also valid subsequence provided s(0,6-i) is valid subsequence.

3.> start filling up Valid Array from last to 0 element : -

a.> take a indice from hash table entry corresponding to S[j] where j is current indice of Valid Array we are analysing.

b.> Check whether indice is in Valid(j+1) if less then add (indice-i,indice) where i in range(1,k+1) into Valid(j) Hash Table

example:-

S = "abc"  T  = "ababbc"

iteration 1 :

j = len(S) = 3

S[3] = 'c'

Symbol Table : c = 6

add (5,6),(4,6),(3,6) as K = 2 in Valid(j)

Valid(3) = {(5,6),(4,6),(3,6)}

j = 2

iteration 2 :

S[j] = 'b'

Symbol table: b  = 2 4 5

Look up 2 in Valid(3) => not found => skip

Look up 4 in Valid(3) => found => add Valid(2) = {(3,4),(2,4),(1,4)}

Look up 5 in Valid(3) => found => add Valid(2) = {(3,4),(2,4),(1,4),(4,5)}

j = 1

iteration 3:

S[j] = "a"

Symbol Table : a = 1 3

Look up 1 in Valid(2) => not found

Look up 3 in Valid(2) => found => stop as it is last iteration

END

as 3 is found in Valid(2) that means there exists a valid subsequence starting at in T

Start = 3

4.> Reconstruct the solution moving downwards in Valid Array :-

example :

Start = 3

Look up 3 in Valid(2) => found (3,4)

Look up 4 in Valid(3) => found (4,6)

END

reconstructed solution (3,4,6) which is indeed valid subsequence

Remember (3,5,6) can also be a solution if we had added (3,5) instead of (3,4) in that iteration

Analysis of Time complexity & Space complexity : -

Time Complexity :

Step 1 : Scan T = O(|T|)

Step 2 : fill up all Valid entries O(|T|*k) using HashTable lookup is aprox O(1)

Step 3 : Reconstruct solution O(|S|)

Overall average case Time : O(|T|*k)

Space Complexity:

Symbol table =  O(|T|+|S|)

Valid table = O(|T|*k) can be improved with optimizations

Overall space = O(|T|*k)

Java Implementation: -

```
public class Subsequence {

private ArrayList[] SymbolTable = null;  
private HashMap[] Valid = null;
private String S;
private String T;




public ArrayList<Integer> getSubsequence(String S,String T,int K) {

    this.S = S;
    this.T = T;
    if(S.length()>T.length())
        return(null);

    S = S.toLowerCase();
    T = T.toLowerCase();

   SymbolTable = new ArrayList[26]; 
   for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
       SymbolTable[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   char[] s1 = T.toCharArray();
   char[] s2 = S.toCharArray();

   //Calculate Symbol table

   for(int i=0;i<T.length();i++) {
      SymbolTable[s1[i]-'a'].add(i);       
   }

  /* for(int j=0;j<26;j++) {
       System.out.println(SymbolTable[j]);
   }
  */

   Valid = new HashMap[S.length()];

   for(int i=0;i<S.length();i++)
       Valid[i] = new HashMap<Integer,Integer >();


   int Start = -1;

   for(int j = S.length()-1;j>=0;j--) {

      int index = s2[j] - 'a';
      //System.out.println(index);

      for(int m = 0;m<SymbolTable[index].size();m++) {

          if(j==S.length()-1||Valid[j+1].containsKey(SymbolTable[index].get(m))) {

              int value = (Integer)SymbolTable[index].get(m);

              if(j==0) {
                  Start = value;
                  break;
              }

              for(int t=1;t<=K+1;t++) {
                  Valid[j].put(value-t, value);
              }
          }

      }

   }

 /*  for(int j=0;j<S.length();j++) {
       System.out.println(Valid[j]);
   }
 */  

   if(Start != -1) {        //Solution exists

       ArrayList subseq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       subseq.add(Start);
       int prev = Start;
       int next;

       // Reconstruct solution 
       for(int i=1;i<S.length();i++) {
           next = (Integer)Valid[i].get(prev);
           subseq.add(next);
           prev = next;
       }

      return(subseq); 
   }

   return(null);


}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Subsequence sq = new Subsequence();
    System.out.println(sq.getSubsequence("abc","ababbc", 2));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Consider a recursive approach: let `int f(int i, int j)` denote the minimum possible gap at the beginning for S[i...n] matching T[j...m]. `f` returns `-1` if such matching does not exist. Here's the implementation of `f`:

```
int f(int i, int j){
    if(j == m){
        if(i == n)
            return 0;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    if(i == n){
        return m - j;
    }

    if(S[i] == T[j]){
        int tmp = f(i + 1, j + 1);
        if(tmp >= 0 && tmp <= k)
            return 0;
    }
    return f(i, j + 1) + 1;
}
```

If we convert this recursive approach to a dynamic programming approach, then we can have a time complexity of `O(nm)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that *usually** **runs in O(N) and takes O(m) space,** where m is  length(S).

It uses the idea of a surveyor's chain:
Imagine a series of poles linked by chains of length k.
Achor the first pole at the beginning of the string.
Now cary the next pole forward until you find a character match.
Place that pole.  If there is slack, move on to the next character; 
else the previous pole has been dragged forward, and you need to go back 
and move it to the next nearest match. 
Repeat until you reach the end or run out of slack.

```c
typedef struct chain_t{
    int slack;
    int pole;
 } chainlink;


int subsequence_k_impl(char* t, char* s, int k, chainlink* link, int len)
{
  char* match=s;
  int extra = k; //total slack in the chain

  //for all chars to match, including final null
  while (match<=s+len){
     //advance until we find spot for this post or run out of chain
     while (t[link->pole] && t[link->pole]!=*match ){
        link->pole++; link->slack--;
        if (--extra<0) return 0; //no more slack, can't do it.
     }
     //if we ran out of ground, it's no good
     if (t[link->pole] != *match) return 0;

    //if this link has slack, go to next pole
     if (link->slack>=0) { 
        link++; match++;
        //if next pole was already placed,
        while (link[-1].pole < link->pole) {
          //recalc slack and advance again
          extra += link->slack = k-(link->pole-link[-1].pole-1);
          link++; match++;
        }
        //if not done
        if (match<=s+len){
          //currrent pole is out of order (or unplaced), move it next to prev one
          link->pole = link[-1].pole+1; 
          extra+= link->slack = k;         
        }
     }
    //else drag the previous pole forward to the limit of the chain.
     else if (match>=s) {
        int drag = (link->pole - link[-1].pole -1)- k;
        link--;match--;
        link->pole+=drag;
        link->slack-=drag;
     }
  }
  //all poles planted.  good match
  return 1;
}

int subsequence_k(char* t, char* s, int k)
{
  int l = strlen(s);
  if (strlen(t)>(l+1)*(k+1)) 
     return -1;   //easy exit
  else {
     chainlink* chain = calloc(sizeof(chainlink),l+2);
     chain[0].pole=-1; //first pole is anchored before the string
     chain[0].slack=0;
     chain[1].pole=0; //start searching at first char
     chain[1].slack=k;
     l = subsequence_k_impl(t,s,k,chain+1,l);
     l=l?chain[1].pole:-1; //pos of first match or -1;
     free(chain);
  }
  return l;
}
```

* I'm not sure of the big-O. I initially thought it was something like O(km+N). In testing, it averages less than 2N for good matches and less than N for failed matches.
...but.. there is a strange degenerate case.  For random strings selected from an alphabet of size `A`, it gets much slower when `k = 2A+1`.  Even this case it's better than O(Nm), and the performance returns to O(N) when k is increased or decreased slightly.  [Gist Here](https://gist.github.com/ashelly/7610713) if anyone is curious.